# Installed pure-ftpd on CentOS 5, removed it, but still running

Tags: centos5, ftp

This is basically my first post on serverfault, although I do watch Stackoverflow multiple times. I've recently purchased a VPS and started to configure it.

Since most of my working are design related, I wish to use FTP as many times as possible.

I've installed pure-ftpd, remove it after an issue where I couldn't logon with a new username created. I've installed vsftpd, couldn't get it to have a username, remove that.

But, it seems that pure-ftpd is still running.

Some commands reports that may be helpful:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:ftp                       *:*                         LISTEN      11359/pure-ftpd (SE
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdomain:smtp  *:*                         LISTEN      11633/sendmail: acc
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                     *:*                         LISTEN      3512/mysqld        
tcp        0      0 *:http                      *:*                         LISTEN      14065/httpd        
tcp        0      0 *:ftp                       *:*                         LISTEN      11359/pure-ftpd (SE
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN      12078/sshd      


[root@vs home]# which pure-ftpd
/usr/bin/which: no pure-ftpd in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

Basically, I wish to either fully remove it as I'm trying to keep my CentOS running without packages that I don't need. Or make it run, but make it run with a virtual user that I need with chroot access to /home directory.

Comment: Oh, I've used ./configure && make install-strip to install it and then ./configure uninstall to remove it from the directory I've installed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the process is still running.  Try killing it:

```
kill 11359
```

or

```
pkill pure-ftpd
```

Comment: It did the trick. I suppose ftp will be disabled for good now. Thank you @ Cakemox